# Evaluating LSTM with custom features

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am new to machine learning but I wanted to understand something that I came across in another post. The person had data that looked like this:

> Age, Gender, Description
>   22, M, "purchased a phone"
>   35, F, "shopping for kids"

The person created a model that combined an LSTM output for the description feature with age.

```
lstm = LSTM(300, dropout=0.3, recurrent_dropout=0.3)(embed)  
agei = Input(shape=(1,))  
conc = Concatenate()(lstm, agei)`
```

My understanding is that there are 300 outputs coming from the LSTM and they all become seperate inputs along with the age which gives a total of 301 inputs that are then fed into a neural network. I need help understanding what the output of LSTM is and if we need to normalize the values with the age feature before feeding data into a neural network. Any help in understanding is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, there is now a 301-long vector going in to the following stages of processing. *I would also call the LSTM a part of the NN, though. From the code you show, it seems that you're going to optimize it together with rest of the network anyway.*
2. The output of the LSTM is 300-long vector describing the Description field. *Hopefully, since you didn't show us how data is fed into a model.*
3. Yes, I'd strongly recommend that you normalize the age data before feeding it into the model. Mean-variance normalization should do a decent job.
4. *You're missing the Gender feature.*

Comment: Ok so if I have a 301 long vector now and I do normalize the age feature would the 300 other features just overpower the information being provided by the 1 age feature? To counteract  this could I duplicate my age nodes so I have 300 age nodes with the same input coming in giving me a total of 600 nodes but now the age has just as many nodes as the LSTM outputs so they are weighed the same?

Comment: Also my input for LSTM is an embedding layer I create, the description is tokenized into an array of integers and then fed into the embedding layer. The problem is now I don't know what the range of the numbers coming out of the LSTM are. Looking up the description for the output of LSTM, I am having trouble understanding the output. I think I need to know the values in order to properly normalize the age field.

Comment: No, they will not overpower it, at least if your LSTM has a decent initialization (which you kind of get for free in Keras). It's ok to have 300 numbers for Description a 1 for Age. Intuitivelly, you need many more numbers to describe a sentence from a natural language. The following layer will pick whatever it finds useful. And duplicating nodes is generally a rather bad idea and I definitely advise against it.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense, so the neural network is doing the work of determining the weights of the features. The 300 outputs coming from LSTM should have a lot of redundant information that should end up being weighed less than other features that only have one node of information assuming it has relevant information to give.